# Layout inside Scrollview not fitting the screen size correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that the output looks like this:

[The layout that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X76X3.png)

This is the code I use for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/first_grey"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/first_grey"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgBackgroundHomeGuest"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/diversity" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_home_view"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentSpinnerCity"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"                                  android:background="@drawable/box_corners_round_white">

                        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:paddingStart="16dp"
                            android:paddingRight="16dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

                        </Spinner>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentSpinnerCategory"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/box_corners_round_white"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/contentSpinnerCity" >

                        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:paddingStart="16dp"
                            android:paddingRight="16dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

                        </Spinner>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btnNearMeHome"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/contentSpinnerCategory"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/box_corners_round_red" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search_white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/search" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/txtWelcomeHome"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/fourth_grey"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/guest.home.welcome_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/fourth_grey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView android:id="@+id/btnArrowDown"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/fa_sort_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeFooter"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView  android:id="@+id/becomeAHostHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/fourth_grey"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/guest.home.BecomeAHost.header"/>

            <TextView  android:id="@+id/becomeAHostDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/fourth_grey"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/guest.home.BecomeAHost.description"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnBecomeAHost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_corners_round_red"
                android:text="@string/menu.become_a_host"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

I want to set the layout homeHeader to fit the device screen.

I tried getting the current screen size and then set his height to the layout like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;

final LinearLayout linearLeft = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeHeader);
LayoutParams params = linearLeft .getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = height;
```

However, when I run it, my output looks like this:

[The screen output in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBLOd.png)

Tyvm for any help!

Comment: what's the size of the image? I can just imagine that you are not stretching the image to fit the screen.

Comment: It's 959 x 1280. I used wrap_content for his height because if I use a certain size the image would be damaged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using `android:weightSum="1"` for the `homeHeader` layout and then for his childs `layout_weight` did the work that I wanted for setting the size for each layout.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set its height and the imageview's to `match_parent`? Let us know if it works, please. Cheers :)

Comment: the imageview can't be match parent because the first layout  goes to the icon that is next to the phrase "Start discovering amazing things to do"